# Angular: disable button prev and next button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multistep form in angular and i have 2 buttons 1.next 2.prev .
how can i disable prev button when user is in first step and how to disable next button when user is in last step .
**here is my code :**

```
 <span class="prev">
                <input type="button" value="فرم قبلی" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$broadcast('Prev')" />
                       </span> 
                <span class="next">
                <input type="button" value="فرم بعدی" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$broadcast('Next')" />
                         </span>
```

Comment: We will need more context. Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: i wanted to, but there is lots of code, but you imagine something like this http://jsfiddle.net/glenn_antoine/rNudn/

Comment: i want something like this : ng-class="{disabled: !hasNextStep()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a member in your scope to define the current step and use ng-disabled to enable/disable buttons

```
<span class="prev">
      <button value="فرم قبلی" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.prev()" ng-disabled="vm.currentStep == 1" >Previous</button>
    </span>
    <span class="next">
      <button value="فرم بعدی" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.next()" ng-disabled="vm.currentStep == 2" >Next</button>
    </span>
```

This is a working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nEyYEROk2xv0mFNMEb5g?p=preview

Comment: thx,do you know how can i get the current step in ui-router ?

Comment: your child step screens/templates can share the parents controller where you can define the current step in.